# Re-deploy spring boot service without restart?

Tags: java, rest, deployment, spring-boot, architecture

I have developed a micro service (Spring Boot REST service, deployed as executable JAR) to track all activities from third party projects as my requirement and its working now.

Currently it's working apart of some projects, and now I have updated service with some additional features.

But I can't  move it to live server without restarting the existing service as it is deployed as jar. I'm afraid to restart my service, restart may be leads to lose data of integrated projects.

What improvements can I make in my architecture to solve my problem?

Comment: There is a way to do this using [Hot Swapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html) but that may not work for you if you're deploying JARs. Also it isn't made to work for classes when you make drastic code changes.

Comment: thank you for the response , need to re deploy classes also

Comment: What you describe is basically the territory of running multiple instances of your services bound to a service registry. That will allow you to bring them down for upgrade one at a time while there is always at least one instance still running and available for clients. That is not trivial to setup however. A google for "microservice service registry" is a good start.

Comment: @Gimby ,Is it possible to do same with Eureka server ?I am using  eureka as service registry

Comment: @Jamsheer I'm not familiar with Eureka, but I'm sure it has a manual.

Comment: @Gimby , Finally done it using by the help of Eureka ,Thank you for your help

Comment: @Gimby ,You can answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally  got a  solution as commented by @Gimby  .

We can do it by deploying multiple instances of  services and it bound to a service registry ,Here i achieved it by using eureka as registry service and also used zuul as proxy .

Answer (score 2):

What about [JRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) plugin. It worked perfectly for me, but, unfortunately, it's not a free app. Like alternative, (i used this approach with Spring MVC, with Spring Boot it could be otherwise), I set up a soft link in work directory on a compiled path in JBoss (in my case it was dir with name target and *.class and *.jar files). As for me, the first solution with JRebel is the most appropriate for you.